# Redirecting back to your site after checking out in 2checkout?

Tags: drupal, ubercart, 2checkout

I've setup a drupal site before where I DID NOT specify an approved URL in 2checkout, and it returned back to my site. However, on another site, this is not happening. What am I missing?

I am using Drupal, with Uber Cart and the standard 2checkout payment module.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurred because of how 2Checkout handles the approved URL that your cart passes in using the `x_receipt_link_url` parameter. If the domain in the URL matches the domain registered to your 2Checkout account, the buyer will be returned. If it does not, 2Checkout reverts back to the approved URL that you setup on the Site Management page. Ubercart dynamically generates the approved URL for each sale so the domain you are selling from must match the domain on your 2Checkout account.

Answer (score 1):

For 2checkout, you have to set the approval URL in your account on 2checkout site. Go to `Account->Site Management` and at the end Approved URL.

Answer (score -1):

You will get help from [here](http://www.2checkout.com/community/blog/newest/a-comprehensive-overview-of-direct-return)

Comment: 404 not found link